# Calculate the Earth’s velocity in its orbit (assumed to be circular) around the Sun

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Data:

- GM of the Sun: $\text{GM} = 1.327 \times 10^{20} \;\mathrm{m^3 s^{-2}}$
- Radius of the Earth’s orbit: $r_{Earth} = 1.496 \times 10^{11} \;\mathrm{m}$
- Orbital period of a planet in seconds: $T = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2}{GM}r^3}$

How does one go about solving this knowing that $V = \sqrt{\frac{\text{GM}}{r}}$?

How would I rearrange or use this formula to get the correct answer?

Comment: Hi @ShatteredPheonix. I have tried to improve the readability of your question. Please let me know, if anything is wrong.

Comment: Just to double-check, whart exactly are you solving for?

Comment: @Steeven you broke the exponents (10^20, 10^11)

Comment: @Jasper Actually not, but I see the intention and made the edit just now.

Comment: @Steeven You have broken the exponents (10^20 and 10^11) just like Jasper said, Since I am new to doing this I have no idea how to fix them

Comment: @DarthPlagueis I am trying to find the Earths Orbital Velocity, So I am solving for V I would guess, but don't understand how to use the formula correctly.

Comment: See my answer, I have derived $v$ for you to show you where it comes from and given you the answer. I assume you are GCSE/A-level?

Comment: @DarthPlagueis Actually, this is from a Masters level past paper in 2013 - 2014 for Space Engineering, I can't believe its a simple case of plugging in the numbers

Comment: Apologies if I came across patronising. How many marks in comparison to the other questions does the examiner give?

Comment: @DarthPlagueis no problem it does seem basic to me but I can't get my head round it being so simple, Its a 4 Part Question and for this particular part it gives 5%, however my confusion is that from my understanding, in your answer you have just plugged in the numbers but logically that means you have Square Rooted the the Suns GM divided by the Earths R to get the Earths Orbital Velocity...is this even allowed?

And if this is the case then why is the Orbital Period even been given to us?

Comment: Perfectly valid.

Comment: @DarthPlagueis That blows my mind lol, and here I was searching through the Internet and many physics books trying to find out why I have been given the Orbital Period.

Comment: You can use it in your derivation and direct observables. So, in essence you know the orbital period to be 365.26 days yes? Assuming we can't directly observe the mass of the Sun. So I have added the velocity as a function of orbital radius and orbital period. This can be done by re-arranging $T$ for $GM$, and then plugging into the expression for $v$.

Comment: @DarthPlagueis You sir, are a genius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the rotation frequenct or angular frequency of Earth: $\omega=2\pi/T$ (assuming the Earth's orbit to be a perfect circle).

We therefore have:

$$
T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}
$$

And we know velocity is:
$$
v=\frac{d}{T}\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,v=\frac{\omega{r}}{2\pi}
$$

$$
\frac{r}{v}=\sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2}{GM}r^3}
$$
$$
\frac{r^{2}}{v^{2}}=\frac{4\pi^2r^3}{GM}\,\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\,=\frac{GM}{4\pi^2r^3}
$$
$$
\therefore{\left(\frac{2\pi{r}}{T}\right)}=2\pi{\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}}}
$$
So when the $2\pi$ cancels we are left with an expression for $r/T$, which we all know and love as speed/velocity. Hence (using the above expression for the orbital period, $T$):
$$
v=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}}=\frac{2\pi{r}}{T}
$$
For the values you are quoting, the Earth's orbital speed is 29783 m s$^{-1}$ (It really is as simple as plugging in the values you have got for $GM$ and $r$ to get v, taking the square root of course).

Addendum:

To get to $v=\omega{r}/2\pi$ use $\omega=2\pi/T$ and re-arrange for $T$ giving:

$$
T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}
$$

Hence, $v=r/T$ (i.e., speed is distance divided by time):

$$
v=\frac{r}{T}=\frac{\omega{r}}{2\pi}
$$

Comment: This calculation is of course an approximation, and a mean value. The Earth's actual orbit is an ellipse. Hence, you could quote something like $\sim$30 km s$^{-1}$.

Comment: This answers great! I'm just having difficulty understanding how to go from v=d/T ⇒ v=ωr/2π. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShatteredPheonix Will update it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Orbit radius is about [*93 million miles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_orbit), times $2\pi$, divided by (365.26 days times 24 hours/day), gives you miles per hour. Do it in metric if you want.

I assume this problem is homework, and the teacher wants *you* to do the calculation (not anyone on this site).

Comment: Nope this is not homework, I am looking at a past paper from my course and trying to do it on my own, so it's completely fine.